# How to run php command input STDIN to accept input while running apache server on window machine

Tags: php

I"m new to php.  I'm running code that interact with google calendar api, that is supposed to accept
a command input for a verification that i get on the screen.  I get that but I don't know if i should have already have the command window up because command line input isn't launching when the program gets to the file where the code gets executed.  I'm a bit confused and have not been able to figure this out over a few days.

Should i already have the command up and running and if i'm supposed to how do i launch it with my current php file.  When i was trying to launch it i was getting error.  I assumed that the command i was
using in top of my php would automatically open up command for me to enter my verification that i get 
from my webpage screen.  Any help would greatly appreciated
Here is my set up

apache webserver 2.4 
php 7.2.10 
window

here is the error i'm getting when i try to run this php file

PHP Warning:  require_once(./vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\booking\TrashItToken.php on line 5

Warning: require_once(./vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\booking\TrashItToken.php on line 5
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Apache24\htdocs\booking\TrashItToken.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Apache24\htdocs\booking\TrashItToken.php on line 5

```
    <?php
 $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
//define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
// include your composer dependencies
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
#defined('STDIN') or define('STDIN', fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */

class AppToken
{
    function getClient()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig('./xxxxxx.json');
        $client->setApplicationName('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events");
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); 

        // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        // time.
         $tokenPath = './includes/token.json';
         if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
            $msg = "We entered the if statement and found the token.";
            error_log($msg, 0);
             $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
             $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);


         }

     // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            $msg1 = "We didn't find the token or its expired.";
            error_log($msg1, 0);
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            } else {
                 // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';

                $msg2 = "We request authorization from the user.";
                error_log($msg2, 0);
                $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));//this is part where code fails

                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    $msg3 = "An error occured after access token.";
                    error_log($msg3, 0);
                   throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }
            // Save the token to a file.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));


        }

        return $client;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I messed up how i understood it.  I had to change my code to be able to call the function since i was calling the function from another php file. So i changed my file to call the function when i called the php file from my editor.

```
$myapptoken = new AppToken();
$mytoken =  $myapptoken->getClient();
```

The command i used to run my php file

php C:\Apache24\htdocs\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx.php